# Is there a way to list the elements of a package in Sparx Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I found the way to get the list but I can't access the names of the elements in it.

Here is my Java code:

```
//Find the package
var packageElement = Repository.GetPackageByGuid("{BB6563A2-EECC-4673-AE51-D01D159BA51F}");

//Find the elements list
var elementCollection = packageElement.Elements;

//Try to get the list in a string
var appList = ""
for (var i = 0; i < elementCollection.Count; i++)
{
    appList += elementCollection[i];
}

//Put the result in my Custom Table
theGrid.SetCell(1, 2, "AppList: " + appList);
theGrid.SetCell(1, 1, "Element Count: " + elementCollection.Count);

//update xml record
theGrid.Update();
```

elementCollection.Count return 13

But appList returns unknownunknownunknown...

Do you know how to get a string with all the elements name extracted from the elementCollection variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bracket I have to use the GetAt() method

```
for (var i = 0; i < elementCollection.Count; i++)
{
    appList += elementCollection.GetAt(i).Name;
}
```

[Collection Class](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/automation/collection.html)

Comment: in C# you can also do a `foreach` on EA.Collections. Not sure if that works in Java as well.

Comment: @GeertBellekens And in Python you can do a `for e in collection:`